# How to have multiple session inside a unique phantomjs execution?

Tags: session, cookies, browser, phantomjs

I was wondering if it's possible to have multiple session inside a single phantomjs execution.

What I mean is to have for example 2 different page objects, having their own cookies and nothing in common.

```
var system = require('system');

var page1 = require('webpage').create();
var page2 = require('webpage').create();

var url = 'https://google.it';

page1.open(url, function(){

  var cookies = page1.cookies;
  console.log('Page1 - Listing cookies:');
  for(var i in cookies) {
    console.log('Page1', cookies[i].name + '=' + cookies[i].value);
  }
  //phantom.exit();

});

page2.open(url, function(){

  var cookies = page2.cookies;
  console.log('Page2 - Listing cookies:');
  for(var i in cookies) {
    console.log('Page2', cookies[i].name + '=' + cookies[i].value);
  }
  //phantom.exit();

});
```

In this case, both the pages have the same cookies. Doesn't exists a way to maintain different sessions?